# Why does Sulfur have 12 valence electrons in the Sulfate ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, electrons, valence-bond-theory

So I am completely and utterly confused about why sulfur has $12$ valence electrons. I understand in it's configuration, it has $2$ electrons for the $3\mathrm s$ subshell, and $4$ electrons from its $3\mathrm p$ subshell, and it can use the $3\mathrm d$ subshell since its in period $3$. Therefore it is able to exceed the octet, and form more than just $4$ covalent bonds.

But how exactly do you calculate the exact number of "**$12$ electrons**" in the valence electron, which thus allows it to participate in $6$ covalent bonds with oxygen in the sulfate ion, $\ce{SO4^2-}$? I can't seem to understand.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It doesn't and it was already discussed here.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/hypervalency-and-the-octet-rule

Comment: more precisely I recommend this answer: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/5242/9961

Comment: none of those answers explain how sulfur has specifically 12 valence electrons. I know it can exceed the octet, but how do we figure out, but HOW MUCH the octet is exceeded by?

Comment: Sulphur has six valence electrons. It is in group 16. I don’t get how you could assume any other valence electron count. Also, sulphur does not exceed the octet.

Comment: in the Sulfate ion it has 12 valence electrons though?

Comment: Then see this http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/why-does-sulfate-have-this-structure

Comment: The sulphate ion is made up of sulphur (6), four oxygens (4 · 6 = 24) and two additional electrons for the charge. Sulphur has six valence electrons, full stop.

Answer (score 0):

Sulfur has 6 Valence electrons, 2 in the first shell, 8 in the second shell, and 6 in the outermost layer (third layer). They can determine the number of kernel electrons and the number of valence electrons due to the bonds they form, for example Sulfur is more likely to form ions with the Alkaline earth metals and form different covalent bonds. In the case of SO4, Sulfur is sharing electrons with 4 Oxygen atoms forming a covalent bond but the overall charge is not 0, it's -2, so it's not exceeding the octet law, it's just a polar covalent bond, this has to do with electronegativity but that's a different story.